# Any appropriate synonym of "forcibly"

Tags: single-word-requests

Please suggest a better word instead of *forcibly* for this case.

> functionality of **forcibly** getting data from server..

So the data is not coming from the server automatically; you need to "force" it to come. However, I think that forcibly is not the right word here. What really happens in this case: the Refresh button makes the app take the data from the server/db by passing the cache. So I want to emphasize that by hitting Refresh the user "forces" to get data to come NOT from cache.

Comment: What other words have you considered? Why not just use *forcibly*?

Comment: I have little idea what other word can be used here.  I thought to write more specifically: bypass cache and retrieve the data from DB.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain that.

Comment: Because that introduces alternatives like *uncached* or *real-time* or something similar that doesn't actually mean *forcibly* at all. But then you're not actually forcing the database to give up data against its will, either.

Comment: "Compellingly" is perhaps more appropriate.

Comment: What ws wrong with the suggestions made by a thesaurus?

Comment: None of the words suggested by a thesaurus  seem right to me. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/forcibly

Comment: According to OP's edit, the functionality is to "get up-to-date data from the server".

Comment: You're *[actively] **retrieving*** data, as opposed to *[passively] **receiving*** it, as you already said in your comment.

Comment: The functionality of ***hitting*** the database to retrieve the data.

Comment: If you are worried about someone not understanding *refresh* or *reload* well enough, then state the behavior explicitly: *refresh the page (and the cache) from the server*. But that is what *refresh* and *reload* mean. And no, none of this has anything to do with *forcibly*. There is no forcing involved.

Comment: When we hit refresh we're forcing a bypass of the cache.  Just keep *force* as a verb.  That is the most natural way to say this.

Answer (score 4):

I work in IT, and if you wrote

> functionality of **reloading** data from the server

then I would assume you were refreshing the cache.

***Reload*** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reload)

> 3. (Computer Science) computing to fetch the latest updated version of (a web page or document); refresh

Comment: I dont work in IT, but even to me, JonLarby's chaning of the verb (instead of focusing on the adverb) seems to well convey the intended meaning.

Comment: However if we really want to focus on the adverb, can "artificially" be a good one? (I'm answering/asking at the same time because I don't know if it would sound natural to the IT people.)

Answer (score 1):

*Manual* is as an antonym of *automatic*.

> functionality of **manually** getting data from server..

***Manual*** — [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/manual.html)

> 1. Controlled or manipulated by a human operator (not automatically, such as by a computer) or powered by human or animal muscle power (not by an inanimate source of power such as an electric motor, gas engine, or sail)

Comment: The emphasis I want to make here that by hitting the Refresh button  forces that app to take data from DB not the cache. So manually is not exactly what I want so say.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single word that would convey this. I suggest:

> functionality of getting data directly from the server, bypassing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If the information you want to convey is that all caching is bypassed, just be explicit rather than relying on figurative descriptions:

> retrieve data from the server (bypassing all caching)

That said, it is not unnatural in the context of software development to say a process should:

> forcibly retrieve data from the server

...and mean "bypassing a given cache", especially where you've established such a cache exists in the preceding sentence.

You could also say

> retrieve data directly from the server

or

> retrieve fresh data from the server

however these rely on the reader correctly identifying the distinction you're making (so it's best to mention the cache here to make it clear what you mean by "fresh" or "directly").

If the cache is within your control (as opposed to being intermediate between the process you're describing and the server), you could also say the process should:

> invalidate the cache and retrieve data from the server